# Combinatorics. Find the number of three digit numbers from 100 to 999 inclusive which have any digit that is the average of other two?

Tags: combinatorics

Combinatorics. Find the number of three digit numbers from 100 to 999 inclusive which have any digit that is the average of other two? 
i tried to do it by making different cases but the answer did not match.
the answer is 121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if the digits are the same, there are $9$ (those are $111,222,\cdots,999$). If the digits are different, then we can do the following.

Pick any number $a$ between $1$ and $9$ (exactly $9$ possibilities for this). The other number $b$, that is, the one you want to take the average with, must be the same $\mod 2$ (so if $a$ is even, then so is $b$, and if $a$ is odd, so is $b$ - otherwise $\frac{a+b}2$ is not an integer). Let's look at the case where $a$ is odd first (five possibilities) and so is $b$ (four possibilies, since it cannot be equal to $a$ - makes total of 20, and there are $6$ permutations, so that makes 120, but now we got double the actual amounts since we can swap $a$ and $b$, that is, we get the same result for $a=n$ and $b=m$ as $a=m$ and $b=n$, so that makes 60 total possibilities).

We do the same for even $a$ (four possibilities), and so there are $3$ choices for $b$ (that makes $12$ total possibilities, 6 permutations, divide by $2$, makes $36$). Now we have found a total of $9+60+36=105$ numbers. But we still need to find all the numbers with a digit $0$. Since $0$ cannot be the average of the other two (then the number would be $000$), we have $a=0$, so four possibilities for $b$ (because $b$ has to be even for the last digit $\frac{a+b}2=\frac b2$ to be defined), and only $4$ permutations, since the number cannot start with $0$, and we don't divide by two, since $a$ is fixed, which makes a total of $4\cdot 4=16$ possibilities. The total of *all* of those numbers thus is $105+16=121$.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Let the three digits by $a, b, c$ (not necessarily in order) and let $a \le b \le c$.  As one is the average of the other two, $b = c - k = a + k$ (which also means $c = a + 2k$).

$k$ can go from $0$ to $4$.

If $k = 0$, $a = b = c$ and there are 9 such options.

Otherwise there are $a$ can span from $0$ to $9 - 2k$ so there are $9 - 2k + 1$ options.  For example.  if $k = 1$ the options are $(0,1,2)...(7,8,9)$.  That is 8 options.  If $k = 2$ the options are $(0,2,4) ....(5,7,9)$.  That is 6 options.

For $k = 1,2,3,4$ there are 8, 6, 4, 2 options or 20 total.  For each of these options, the digits are all different so there are 6 ways to arrange them.  (abc,acb,bac,bca,cab,cba).  So there are 20*6 =120 ways the digits can be different.

But you can't have the first digit equal to zero. There are four cases where $a = 0$ and $b = k$ and $c = 2k$.  Of those four cases there are two ways to arrange them.  (0bc, and 0cb). So there our 8 "forbidden" cases where the first digit is 0.

So there or 120 - 8 = 112 ways to do this where the digits are not all the same.

And there are 9 ways to do the where the digits *are* all the same.

So there are 112 + 9 = 121 ways total.